# how to subtract the average duration

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying this aggregation but output is displayed in reverse

```js
{
  "SWITCHID": "Z4-W40-SS451A/5",
  "CREATE_DATE": ISODate("2018-02-24T19:00:14.808Z"),
  "RECEIVEDDATE": ISODate("2018-02-24T20:30:14.808Z"),
  "STATUS": "LIGHTS ON",
  "avgduration": 202.50562416666668,
  "offduration": 1.5
} {
  "SWITCHID": "Z4-W40-SS451A/5",
  "CREATE_DATE": ISODate("2018-02-24T19:00:14.808Z"),
  "RECEIVEDDATE": ISODate("2018-02-24T20:30:14.808Z"),
  "STATUS": "LIGHTS OFF",
  "avgduration": 269.5074988888889,
  "offduration": 1.5
}
db.k.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    _id: {
      SWITCHID: "$SWITCHID"
    },
    on_minus_off: {
      $sum: {
        "$cond": [{
          "$eq": ["$STATUS", "ON"]
        }, "$avgduration", {
          $subtract: [0, "$avgduration"]
        }]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

output is:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/5"
    },
    "on_minus_off" : -472.0131230555556
}
```

but expected output is:

```
202.50562416666668-269.5074988888889=-67.00187472222222
```

Comment: Please update the question with ACTUAL and EXPECTED output - they are not even close in format

Comment: @ mplungjan  my docs swichID both are same but Status different  first document "avgduration": 202.50562416666668- second document  avgduration": 269.5074988888889 = 67.00187472222222 this is my expected out put but iam not getting this out put any suggest me

Comment: Please update the question. You can edit and add the information in a readable format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your condition is wrong

```
"$eq": ["$STATUS", "ON"]
```

it should be

```
"$eq": ["$STATUS", "LIGHTS ON"]
```